# Horizontal stripes on top of youtube video in html5 mode

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video, h.264, codec

I suggested to try html5 mode on Youtube, but I'm forced with rendering problem.
Horizontal stripes appears on top of video frame in dynamic scenes.

Also I see the same problem for some videos on sites like Vimeo and others.

This problem is reproducible in FireFox and Chrome.
On my opinion it's looks like a codec issue.

[image]

How can I solve it? Should I install some specific codec or tune my browser?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of problem is Intel HD Graphics (4000 in my case) video card. All I was needed for solving it, is just to update my video driver.